# Tableview is affected by paging

Tags: android, tableview

I have recently been implementing the most recent version of the tableview published in github and it turns out that when trying to draw the rows in the tableview I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
     at java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:437)
     at cu.tableview.pagination.Pagination.paginateData (Pagination.java:128)
     at cu.tableview.pagination.Pagination.reloadPages (Pagination.java:106)
     at cu.tableview.pagination.Pagination.initialize (Pagination.java:102)
     at cu.tableview.pagination.Pagination. <init> (Pagination.java:85)
     at cu.tableview.pagination.Pagination. <init> (Pagination.java:63)
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: No I cannot help you ;-) as you don't give much to go on, good questions give a reproducible code example

Comment: The code is available in https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView/tree/master/app

Comment: Pagination is not by default turned on in the Sample App provided with the library, even if I turn it on and rebuild everything works as expected for me. You need to give more details about what other changes you are making or what environment you are building and running it with.